# vimrc file variations when using git

Tags: git, vim

I am currently using git to version control my vimrc file. However, on one computer I want the vimrc file to be slightly different (to change the gui font). How can I do this easily? Is there a way to ignore that specific line? Or do I put them on different branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd vote branches. A file at a single point in a single branch can't have two different states. That's kind of what version control is all about. Branches are the way that you represent that more than one state of a file (or set of files) exists.

Comment: And what you want to do is be very careful about generic vs. specialized changes. You should make the generic changes on the generic branch, commit there, and merge into the specialized branches.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one thing that you want to have host-specific, then

you can also rely on the hostname and write an equivalent of the
line of shell script below, I give the example in shell cause it's so
brief (quite likely it'll take a few more lines in a vim script):

```
   % source `hostname`-fonts.sh
```

If you have your set-up based on the same git repo which I use
(https://github.com/sunaku/.vim or a fork), then you can add
your own script in ~/.vim/config/99-local-fonts.vim and make
a condition there to look for a file with a hostname in it, if
that doesn't exist apply a default setting. You can place such
file somewhere in the repository, but where it doesn't auto-load
scripts from, i.e. ~/.vim/local/ or similar.

If you use branches, then all the time you will have to make sure
you pull new changes in ...etc
Branches are good if there is a lot of files which are different.